# Full width horizontal navigation

Tags: css

I currently have a pseudo full width horizontal navigation that has been created by setting margins on each of the list elements that causes the navigation to expand out to be almost full-width. The problem with this is that if anything in the navigation changes, it will break and I will have to figure out the new exact margins to make it extend to full width. Also, different browsers change the sizes of my text and other things slightly which means full-width in one browser is too big (and breaks onto another line) in another browser.

So I'm trying to figure out a better solution for this. I have a solution that works for the top-level navigation items, which involves changing the following CSS:

```
ul.menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table;
}

ul.menu > li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}

ul.menu > li:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
}

ul.menu li {
    padding: 12px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}

ul.menu li a {
    padding: 12px 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Top-level navigation]

This seems to be working perfectly, but unfortunately (and predictably), it messes up the sub-menus, which now look like this:

[image: Sub-menu navigation]

I've been playing around with the sub-menu CSS for ages trying to get it to work like it used to, but have been unsuccessful.

Does anyone know what changes I need to make here in order to get the full width navigation working for the top-level elements, while leaving the sub-menus as they were originally?

Comment: I'm trying to adjust your live CSS to your posted "CSS changes" but I'm not getting the sub-menu to break. At this point, I'll have to ask if you could create a fiddle?  I'm not seeing where the problem is cropping up.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jordan, I saved the website out locally then added your additional CSS rules but I'm not getting the same.  Could you create a fiddle with just the new main nav styles?  I can help troubleshoot from there.

Comment: Here is a link to answer that descibes [full width responsive horizontal page navigation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414642/responsive-horizontal-page-sliding-navigation/24465646#24465646)

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand you, but lets see if I can help get you there (or at least closer) while explaining.

To get "full width" you'll want to make sure your container element has:

`position:relative` or `position:absolute`

Your current CSS has

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  /* ... */
```

That's good.  This will mean we can position child elements to be contained within this box, so we can get "full width", so to speak.

Now we want to make sure no lower child elements supersede this rule.  *There is one!*  We want to remove this bit:

```
ul.menu li {
  position: relative; /* remove */
  /* ... */
```

This will cause the sub-menu to be contained within the parent `li` which will cause some problems when we try make it fill the full menu bar's width.

Next up is adjusting the sub-menu.  This selector:

```
ul.menu li ul.sub-menu{ /*... */ }
```

We want the sub-menu to be full width, so we add:

```
width:100%;
```

Now, we already have `min-width:100%` but I like to stick more to `width`, especially if we know we're going doing `100%`.  Perhaps it's my old IE6 bone itching me, but maybe there's a reason for it.  It should work in modern browsers without adding `width:100%`. So take that bit with a grain of salt.

Next up, we want to position the sub-menu by adding:

```
left:0;
top:4.5em;
```

This should place the full width of the sub-menu across the main-menu's width and drop it down just under the main-menu.  Some slight tweeks might be needed depending on your design needs.

From there, we want to flatten out the sub-menu items so they go horizontally.  To do this, we need to remove:

```
ul.menu li ul.sub-menu li {
    width: 100%; /* remove */
    /* ... */
```

and

```
ul.menu li ul.sub-menu li a{
    /* ... */
    display:block; /* remove */
    /* ... */
```

Otherwise, the sub-menu items will just fill the whole space and we'll be back to a vertical design.

I think that's all I did to get a "full width" horizontal sub-menu bar.  I hope that's what you were looking for.  It seemed you had the vertical sub-menu figured out just fine.

I would, however, cross-browser test this solution.  I've only modified in in Chrome's developer tool.

(and I hope I didn't miss any of my developer tool edits)

This might not get you all the way there, but I hope it helps!

Cheers!

ps. I do notice two problems.  Sub-menus with a limited number of items tend to feel squished up against the left side.  Sub-menus with a large number of items will wrap.

That might be ok, or you might want to consider an extra class for small menu's that spread out the items a little better.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, that's not quite what I was looking for. Basically, I originally had the navigation menu that is currently live at the link I provided. I have now modified the top-level navigation menu with the CSS code that I listed in my question, in order to make it automatically extend to full-width, regardless of the number of items, etc.

This seems to be working correctly, however the changes made have broken the sub-menus. I want the top-menu navigation to use this updated CSS, while keeping the suh-menus exactly the same as they were originally.

Comment: I see.  This is a browser issue as it looks fine in Chrome.  The sub-menu's are vertically stacked, not horizontally.  Which browser are you testing?  Sorry for mis-understanding your question.

Comment: Well if you're looking at it on [rtt.celero.com.au](http://rtt.celero.com.au), then yes, it will look fine, as that's using the original CSS, not the modified CSS that I included in my question. When you apply the modified CSS, the top-level navigation looks perfect (as shown in screenshot 1), but it breaks the sub-menus (as shown in screenshot 2). I'm hoping someone can help me with modifying the CSS so that the sub-menus will look as they did originally.

Comment: Ah, I get it.  Sorry that confused me.

Comment: No problem! So do you have any ideas on how I can fix the sub-menus so they look like they do on the live version, after having applied the CSS changes I included in the original question? I unfortunately can't apply the changes to the live site since the client and their employees are currently looking at the new site to give their feedback, so I can't just put up a broken version of the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

update this one. hope it will solve your problem.

```
ul.menu > li {
    padding: 12px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
```